# magento add column after product tab in product view page

Tags: magento

I am creating a custom module and want to add another tab after product description tab in product detail page. Below is my xml code for execute:

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="product.description">
        <block type="testimonial/monblock"  name="stockas">
             <action method="setTemplate">
                 <template>testimonial/viewMore.phtml</template>
             </action> 
        </block>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

But it shows under price column. I want to show it under product details tab.
Any one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code after Description block in catalog.xml files

```
<block type="testimonial/monblock"  name="stockas">
         <action method="setTemplate">
             <template>testimonial/viewMore.phtml</template>
         </action> 
 </block>
```

you can add in the above way for any number of tabs needed hope this helps.